# Lengths $l$ of modules satisfy $l(M)=l(M/N)+l(N)$ if $N$ is a submodule of $M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I read the following proposition in the commutative algebra notes of Prof. Dr. Andreas Gathmann and I came up with my own idea to prove the following statement but it looks different than the one given in his notes so I hope someone can help me to check if my idea is correct. Thanks.

Proposition: Let $M,N$ be $A$-modules and let $l(M)$ denote the length of $M$. Let $N$ be an $A$-sub module of $M$. Then $$l(M)=l(M/N)+l(N).$$

My thoughts: It suffices to prove the proposition when both $l(M/N)$ and $l(N)$ are finite.

Claim: Let $\varphi: A \rightarrow B$ be a subjective $R$-module homomorphism, where both $A$ and $B$ are $R$-modules. Then there is a bijection:
$\varphi:$
$\{$Submodules in $A$ containing the kernel of $\varphi\}$
$\to$
$\{$ submodules in $ B \}$, with inverse $\varphi^{-1}:$
$\{$ submodules in $ B \}$
$\to$
$\{$Submodules in $A$ containing the kernel of $\varphi\}$.
We need to see they are both well defined. That is to see the image of a submodule under a module homomorphism is a submodule and preimage of submodule under a surjective module homomorphism is a submodule. (Easy to check).

And we know if $N$ is a submodule of $M$, then the canonical projection $\pi: M\rightarrow M/N$ is a surjective module homomorphism. Then the result follows.

Let $M$ be a module of length $n$ and let $N$ be a submodule. Let $N_1\subset ...\subset N_n=n$ be the chain of submodules of maximal length. Then there exists $m\in \{1,..,n\}$ with $N_m=N$. Then $l(M)=n=m+(n-m)=$ number of submodules in $N$ $+$ number of submodules between $N$ and $M$. But the number of modules between $N$ and $M$ is equal to the number of submodules in $M/N$ by my claim. 
Conversely, if we have $l(N)=m$ and $l(M/N)=n$. Then by the claim the number of submodules in $M/N$ is equal to the number of submodules in $M$ containing $N$. Thus $l(M)=l(N)+l(M/N)$.

Comment: The link between the submodules of $M/N$ and the submodules of $M$ containing $N$ is important, but ultimately the trivial piece of the argument. When you say "Then the result follows" you are sweeping everything worth explaining under the rug.  *What is the relation between a composition series of $M$ and the composition series of $M/N$ and $N$?* That is what you should be talking about.

Comment: Put that in your *post* not in a comment.  Use the edit button to do so.

Comment: @rschwieb sorry. now I have put everything to the post.

Comment: Good, thank you!

Comment: *But the number of modules between  and  is equal to the number of submodules in / by my claim.* This will certainly be interpreted as the number of *all submodules* rather than what you need (the maximum length of a chain between $N$ and $M$.). There could be infinitely many submodules between, and yet the max chain length might be finite.

Comment: To remedy this, can I say there is still a bijection if I restrict to any chain of ideals? I guess not hard to show.

Comment: You argued (correctly) using a chain of maximal length in $N$, and you should do the same in $M/N$.  Intuitively any maximal chain of $M$ should consist of one such piece in $N$ and the remainder corresponding to a chain of submodules containing $N$, which I think is the path you're on.